# Python subprocess.call with cwd not working

Tags: python, cmd, terminal, subprocess

I have tried various things, none work.
Here are my attempts:

```
subprocess.call(['cordova-test android tests --app platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk --device-name=emulator-5554 --no-compile'],
      cwd = ['/Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy'], shell = True)
```

next

```
subprocess.call(['cordova-test android tests --app platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk --device-name=emulator-5554 --no-compile'],
       cwd = shlex.split(['/Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy'])
```

next

```
subprocess.call(['cordova-test android tests --app platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk --device-name=emulator-5554 --no-compile'],
       cwd = ['/Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy'])
```

Comment: What happens? What are the errors?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How is this related to tag [tag:cmd]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, argument line must be a string (with spaces, optionally) or a list of the arguments, but not the command line as sole argument.

Then, current working directory must be a string, not a list.

Try this:

```
subprocess.call(['cordova-test','android','tests','--app','platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk','--device-name=emulator-5554','--no-compile'],
       cwd = '/Users/User/Documents/dev/engineerappcopy')
```

Comment: I think this works with, shell = True at the end. Other wise unknow directory is thrown. However nothing happens... but I think you solved it for now thanks Jean

Comment: okay, `shell=True` it is, when the command is an alias or a function (or a built-in). Glad it worked.